# UDP port scanner by using socket php

Tags: php, sockets, udp

ok, it's easy to code TCP port scanner by using socket but i don't know why it's hard to be the same for UDP

I just want to check if a specific UDP port (say port 500) is open or not.

Here is my code:

```
$ip = '103.12.9.209';
$port = '500';

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);

$result = socket_connect($socket, $ip, $port);

if ($result)
{
    echo "Port is on";
}
else
{
    echo "Port is off";
}

socket_close($socket);
```

The problem is it always return true (port is on) even it's off.

What is the problem? any idea please?

Thanks.

Comment: `udp` is connectionless. To make sure, you'll have to send data (in a manner the receiver understands), and read a response.

Comment: @Wrikken any example please? thanks.

Comment: I found this [useful link](http://www.speedguide.net/faq_in_q.php?qid=173)

Answer (score 1):

You need to send an empty UDP frame to the port in question and check for ICMP responses. If you get ICMP type 2, code 3 (port unreachable) then the port is closed. If you receive other codes like type3, code 1,2,9,10 or 13) the port is filtered. If you receive data or at least don't receive ICMP responses then it can be assumed that the port is open, but however, if there are just no ICMP responses it is not sure that the port is open.

Comment: Could you provide an example or resources can help me with that? thank you.

Comment: Currently trying to hack an example ;) can take a while, will give an update

Comment: You can start to read the docs of icmp (or the wikipedia article will give you all the type and code values and the structure of the ICMP frame)

Comment: It will take some time to elaborate on this. Have something but it's not reliable. [Here is what I have so far](http://pastebin.com/AVMbGAfG). Need to go sleeping and check this again tomorrow.. Btw, for investigation and debugging my Hexdump package is definitely helpful. https://github.com/metashock/Hexdump

Comment: I have tried it and got this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM, expecting T_VARIABLE in /Hexdump.php on line 120`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42306/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-user3001517)

Comment: @user3001517 It requires php >= 5.3

Comment: I will upgrade to 5.3 and re-test, np :)